# How to prevent user not to remove particular character in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, uitextfield

In my iPhone app , i want that UITextField has "+" symbol by default for mobile number.If user want to change mobile number then he/she can. But they don't allow to remove "+" from UITextField. "+" symbol always stay as it is in UITextField.

**For example:-**

+911234567890 - Right Number

911234567890 - Wrong Number. + is required.

I tried with UITextField delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

And also used notification "**UIControlEventEditingChanged**".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: textField supports leftView. There add imageView which has + symbol as UIImage. Or we can use textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange method also.

Comment: I already tried shouldChangeCharactersInRange method mate but not getting any luck

Comment: What did you try with `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` ?

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
If user wants to try to remove "+" then they can't.But this creates problem as should character method consider previous character. Means if user removes characters and reach at "+" and after that user is trying to write any character then this method doesn't allow them to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *head= [textField.text substringToIndex:range.location];
NSString *tail= [textField.text substringFromIndex:range.location];
NSString *phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",head,string,tail];
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSString *deleteString = [tail substringToIndex:1];
    if ([deleteString isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        return NO;
    }
}else if(![self isValidPhoneNumber:phoneNumber]){
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Check valid phone number by regular expression

```
-(BOOL)isValidPhoneNumber:(NSString*)phoneNumber{
NSString *phoneNumberPattern = @"[+]([0-9])*";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",phoneNumberPattern];

BOOL match = [predicate evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
if (match) {
    NSLog(@"VALID");
    return YES;
}else{
    NSLog(@"INVALID");
}
return NO;
}
```

Comment: IMO, checking range is better, as it allows to prevent any first character from being deleted (easier to support your code + reusable). You can also add any character BEFORE the plus with the above code. Added range check-based answer below.

Comment: @DaniilKorotin , you are right. But i exact want "+" so i need to check with string.So, above code is working perfectly in my situation :) .

Comment: Now try moving the cursor before the "+" sign. You can type anything and also remove the plus sign.

Comment: do you want to prevent type anything before + sign?

Answer (score 2):

Prevents any characters from being added before and instead of the first character:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return range.location == 0 && (range.length == 0 || range.length == 1) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here i am using left padding to UITextField.  **txtf** is my UITextField.

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 15, 30)];
lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[lbl setText:@"+"];
_txtf.leftView=lbl;
[_txtf setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```